# Python Telnetlib conectar a porta diferente da 23

Tags: python, telnet

Olá;

Estou tentando fazer um script em python para conectar na porta 12612 do localhost. Rodando o comando telnet no linux, de forma manual, o mesmo executa. Porém, no meu script python, utilizando a biblioteca telnetlib, aparentemente não está conectando. Preciso conectar no console do telnet, e executar algumas tarefas. Segue o código:

```
import os, glob, telnetlib, time

CAMINHO = "/home/admin/deploy"
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = "12612"
TIMEOUT = 2
filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
os.chdir(CAMINHO)

try:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, TIMEOUT)
    tn.set_debuglevel('DEBUG')
    tn.open(HOST, PORT, TIMEOUT)
except ValueError:
    print("Falha ao conectar")

for file in glob.glob("*.jar"):
    arquivoAtual = file.split('_')[0]
    comando = ("file://" + CAMINHO + "/" + file).strip()
    tn.write(("uninstall " + arquivoAtual + "\n"))
    tn.write("install " + comando + "\n")
    tn.write("setbsl 5" + arquivoAtual + "\n")
    tn.write("start " + arquivoAtual + "\n")


tn.write("exit" + "\n")
tn.close()
print('Concluido')
```

Comment: "aparentemente não está conectando" como assim, o que acontece? você recebe algum tipo de erro?

Comment: Nenhum erro, mas também, os comandos não são executados.

Comment: Você recebe a mensagem "Falha ao conectar"? E a mensagem "Concluido" do final?

Comment: Coloquei depois do for um tn.read_all(), e agora dá o seguinte erro:

    python deploy.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "deploy.py", line 32, in <module>
    tn.read_all()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 385, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 576, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
    socket.timeout: timed out

A mensagem concluído aparece se eu tirar o tn.read_all().

Comment: Pode ser que não esteja entrando no `for` - tem certeza que tem arquivos `.jar` no diretório atual? Coloque um `print(file)` dentro do `for` para certificar-se de que os comandos estão sendo enviados

Comment: Sim, os arquivos estão no diretório, eu já havia testado isso ( com um print ). É bem estranho isso, eu li num lugar que, a biblioteca foi feita para trabalhar na porta 23 com autonegociação. Qualquer porta diferente, que não tenha autonegociação, pode acontecer da biblioteca não conseguir interagir com o servidor ftp. O ftp em questão é o console do osgi do idempiere. Estou fazendo um script para atualizar os plugins novos da aplicação com python.

Comment: Opa, peraí, você disse que o servidor é FTP?? Achei que era telnet!! Para acessar servidores ftp, você deve usar o módulo `ftplib` e não `telnetlib`.

Comment: cara, desculpa. É telnet sim, só na porta 12612.

Answer (score 0):

Tem um problema no seu código, que é a utilização de `tn.open()` após criar a instância com nome de servidor e porta.

Se você criou o servidor assim:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, TIMEOUT)
```

O `open` já foi chamado para você. Ao chamar `tn.open()` mais tarde você estará invalidando a conexão, como diz na documentação:

> Do not reopen an already connected instance.

Comment: Eu li na documentação o seguinte (https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) que a instância da classe está inicialmente desconectada, use open() para conectar.  Mas não continuei lendo, onde diz que se passar pro construtor os dados, ele já faz a conexão

Comment: Mesmo sem utilizar o open(), não conecta. Defini um timeout de 20 segundos, e coloquei tn.read_all() no final, agora dá socket.timeout().

Comment: OPa - essa porta aí - ele tá passando como string. Acho que tem que ser número.